# Hosting a WCF service inside the company

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF service which is ready to be hosted. I need to host it on a computer inside the company and it should be accessed only by the people inside the company without any external access. You can assume that all of the computers inside the company are connected to each other. How should I do this correctly?

Comment: Install it on a computer not accessible from Internet.

Comment: Yes, but how can I communicate with it inside my network?

Comment: Umm... IIS/Windows Services? _You_ know the requirements better than _we_ do.

Comment: It is irrelivant which one of the two is used, my concern is more about how should I specify the endpoint inside the config file when it comes to hosting it inside a local network? Should I use the IP address of the computer on which it is hosted? Newbie at communication here >.>

Comment: Endpoint has little relevance. It's either externally accessible or it isn't. As long as it's behind the DMZ and you can't get to it without VPN/being on the network, you should be good.

Comment: But it is the endpoint that specifies to which computer the cilent application connect correct? Do I need to provide any other information in order to connect to it or is it just that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588265/understanding-wcf-windows-authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this in the following way :

1.Disable your firewall for private networks
2.Host your application on a free port
3.Ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

Host the service using IIS or wrap it as a Windows Service. Either way, that's how you *host* it.

Securing it is up to you or your IT department and isn't within the scope of SO. If you need a security lesson, jump on over to [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/).